# How to quickly add a new top level heading in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

If I already have an established heading structure in Microsoft Word, what is the quickest way for me to add a *new* top level heading?

For example, if I already have an H1 heading assigned to vehicles makes (i.e. Ford, Chevy, etc), but later decide that I want to add a higher level heading called "Vehicles", do I have to go through all my H1 headings and change them to H2 manually?

See attached screenshot
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoVbL.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right-Arrow</kbd> to demote
a selected header in the document, so H1 becomes H2, H2 becomes H3 etc.

You may do that to the entire document by first pressing
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the whole document.

You may change one particular header style such as H1 to H2 over the
selected text,
by using the Find dialog to replace all H1 styles to H2, using the Format
drop-box and choosing "Style" for both the find and replace boxes,
thus replacing styles but not text.

Comment: That was beautiful!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: Is there a menu item in Word that this shortcuts corresponds to?

Comment: You may find it under ribbon group View, where button Outline will open a new Outlining group. I think that the keyboard shortcuts may be easier to access.